# Unable to type in textview in landscape rotation Ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a textview and few UITextField on my view controller. When i am running in simulator and in portrait mode I can edit in the textfield but when i am rotating in landscape i cannot edit the fields.
Looks bit weird to me . May be I am missing very small thing here.Is there any property that has to be set?

Please suggest/help.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Did you check the frames of the text fields and their superviews? Any debugging at all? Code for rotation / auto-resizing/layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Would be better if you give some code.

By the way, there is high chance that your problem be that you do not resize one of the UITextField superview (parents), so even if the UITextView is visible, events are not caught cause it's in a kind of void place.

But if you give code we can help you more.